# Post image to slack using httr package in R

Tags: r, slack, httr

Slack offers a method to upload files through their api.  The documentation is found here:

[Slack files.upload method](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)

On this page it gives an example of how to post a file:

```
curl -F file=@dramacat.gif -F "initial_comment=Shakes the cat" -F channels=C024BE91L,D032AC32T -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxa-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx" https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

I am trying to translate how to execute this line of code using the httr package in R, with a file in my R working directory.  I'm having trouble translating the different parts of the command.  Here is what I have so far.

```
api_token='******'
f_path='c:/mark/consulting/dreamcloud' #this is also my working directory
f_name='alert_picture.png'

res<-httr::POST(url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload', httr::add_headers(`Content-Type` = "multipart/form-data"), 
      body = list(token=api_token, channels='CCJL7TMC7', title='test', file = httr::upload_file(f_path), filename=f_name))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  read function returned funny value
```

I tried to find better examples to use but so far no luck.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's an example in slackr's own gg_slackr method](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/slackr/blob/master/R/gg_slackr.R#L58-L62), which creates an image of a GGPlot and uploads it to Slack:

```
  res <- POST(url="https://slack.com/api/files.upload",
              add_headers(`Content-Type`="multipart/form-data"),
              body=list(file=upload_file(ftmp),
                        token=api_token, channels=modchan))
```

Your code seems to be passing a path to a directory rather than a file as the `file` parameter - consider changing that parameter to `file=upload_file(paste(f_path, f_name, sep="/")` and see if that fixes your error.

Comment: You are a genius!  Initially it didn't work because the 'modchan' parameter is actually a function to transform the channel name to the channel ID.  Not sure why that wasn't working, but when I replaced it with the actual channel ID it posted the image.  You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad I could help!